# How can I gain ownership of a question I asked as an unregistered user?

Tags: support, user-accounts, association, unregistered-users

I asked a question and mistakenly created an unregistered user. Now I'm unable to access the question and respond to people answering it.

I have created a stack exchange user - how can I gain access to the unregistered account, and preferably move the question to my stack exchange user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to flag the question that you asked for moderator attention, and ask them to merge it into your current account.

Like so:

[image: Click the "flag" link on your question underneath the tags, type a comment in the "other" box, and click the "Flag Question" button.]

Comment: I'm unable to access the question so I can flag it...

Comment: Here is the question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/6803119/859787

Comment: @BozKay: I've flagged it myself, so a moderator should be by to fix things up shortly. I'm not sure why you can't flag it, though. There should be a link to do that any time you're logged in.

Comment: Yep - double checked - no flag option. Perhaps it is because I'm new and only have a rep of 3?

Comment: @BozKay: When your reputation is below 15, you can only flag your own posts. So now that your accounts are merged and you don't *need* to flag it, you can.

Comment: Thanks - I can't vote this up as my rep is only 8... ah well...