# How can a newly registered account flag a previously unregistered account's questions?

Tags: support, user-accounts, association, unregistered-users

I have registered a Stack Exchange OpenID account with Stack Overflow and would like to merge that with an unregistered account on Stack Overflow.  The e-mail addresses are the same in both accounts however the automatic merge failed to work.  Also, whenever I try to access the previous unregistered account through account recovery I am always redirected to the new account so I'm stuck with reputation 1.

In the [FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) it says that the main way to merge accounts is to flag a post for a moderator to merge.  This [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99732/how-can-i-gain-ownership-of-a-question-i-asked-as-an-unregistered-user) has a screen shot of where that flag link is *but* like the OP in the question, I do not have access to the flag link since all I am *stuck* with my newly registered account with 1 reputation on Stack Overflow.

So, apart from me asking somebody to flag it for me, how can a newly registered account flag a previously unregistered account's questions?

Comment: Can you post the links to the two profiles. Then a mod will be able to verify the details and merge the accounts.

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm a little hesitant in doing that since it's not really answering my question.

Comment: The answer is that you need 15 reputation to be able to flag - which shouldn't be too hard to achieve - however, linking to the profiles (by editing your question) is a way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Merged.  Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ChrisF's comment:

> The answer is that you need 15 reputation to be able to flag - which
>   shouldn't be too hard to achieve - however, linking to the profiles
>   (by editing your question) is a way to achieve your goal.

So it seems that quickest way to solve this problem is to write a 'please merge my account' post, just like this one.