# Create account out of anonymous question?

Tags: support, login, unregistered-users

For the sake of simplicity I posted an anonymous question on a Stack Exchange site yesterday. Is there a way to "un-anonymize" the posted question by linking it to an account that will be created (To answer comments and stuff for example)? Since I have given my mail when creating the question, it should be possible right? (I got a mail telling me that I could do it, but when registering, the question still wasn't linked with my account, weirdly. )

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99732/how-can-i-gain-ownership-of-a-question-i-asked-as-an-unregistered-user) does not solve my problem, as it does not work on beta boards (Or at least on some specific boards).

Comment: Thanks, I guess my search was ineffective. You're right, it is a duplicate. @HackerKarma

Comment: @HackerKarma actually it doesnt solve my question, as the startup-board doesnt have a flag button...

Comment: It's not a dup as OP cannot flag questions (other than his own) until he has 15 rep.

Comment: That one is indeed not really dupe, but the faq is, as it deals with the general case.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ahh... I found this comment: 
When your reputation is below 15, you can only flag your own posts. So now that your accounts are merged and you don't need to flag it, you can. –  mmyers Jul 25 '11 at 13:34

Comment: @GandalfSchmidt You could try flagging one of your own posts from another site where you have more than 15 rep and explain to the mod exactly what your problem is ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that!

Comment: @HackerKarma I'm not sure if I understood you right, since the anonymous question I posted still isnt linked to my account? edit: Oh, this was just a quote. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidPostill Do you know how long the moderators usually take to check such a request? And is there a way to know if it was "declined" or ignored?

Comment: @GandalfSchmidt Sorry, no idea. I've never had to do it.

Comment: @GandalfSchmidt Please use the [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page located at the bottom of every page and explain the situation. Someone from our team will have a look at the situation then and help you out. Using flags on other sites is not the best way, since you won't be able to pass on all the information we may need to solve the situation.